# Save JavaScript Variable to Rails Model

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, filepicker

I am using the FileStack API and the filepicker gem (https://github.com/Ink/filepicker-rails). I follow the steps outlined in the doc under Accessing FilePicker File with OnChange. I am attempting to grab the JSON browser response attribute, filename, pass it to my Rails controller via a route, and save it as a :name in my Attachment model.

Attachment/New view

```
<%= filepicker_js_include_tag %>

<%= simple_form_for(@attachment) do |f| %>

<%= f.filepicker_field :title, multiple: 'true', onchange: 'onUpload(event)' %>
<%= f.submit %>

<% end %>

<script>
  function onUpload(event) {
  var name = event.fpfile.filename;
  jQuery.ajax({
   data: { "attachment[name]": name, "attachment[title]": url },
   type: 'post',
   url: "/attachments"
  });
 }
</script>
```

Route

```
post 'attachments/' => 'attachment#create'
```

Attachment Controller

```
    def create

      @attachment = current_user.attachments.build(attachment_params)

      if @attachment.save
        redirect_to attachments_path
      else
        render root_path
      end
end
...

private

    def attachment_params
        params.require(:attachment).permit(:title, :user_id, :name)
    end
```

I have browsed the relevant SO posts which is how I came to this implementation. However when I view my Attachment model in the rails console, name is nil. My data isn't getting passed properly. I am not sure if I am missing a step or am not routing properly. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: did u try like this in ajax `data: { "attachment[name]" : name }` ?

Comment: Please see my updated code above. I added `data: { "attachment[name]" : name }` and I am no longer getting the name params error. But it looks like two POST requests happen as you can see in my Terminal output and name is still nil. Is it getting overwritten?

Comment: When I upload the file and shut down the server (before hitting submit) I then get ` => #<Attachment id: 69, title: nil, created_at: "2016-05-17 05:10:53", updated_at: "2016-05-17 05:10:53", user_id: 2, name: "myFile.doc"> ` when I check the console. However, when I do submit, the title has a value, but name is nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller super messy delete most of them and just keep it simple as like below. That one line will cover for you `current_user.id` and `name`.

```
def create
  @attachment = current_user.attachments.build(attachment_params)
  if @attachment.save
    redirect_to attachments_path
  else
    render root_path
  end
end
```

Also, meanwhile you have params permit

`params.require(:attachment).permit(:name, :title, :user_id)`

You have to pass data like this `"attachment[name]"`, but you are passing it simple `"name"`. Thats the reason getting `Unpermitted parameter: name`. And as @anonymousxxx mentioned remove `:name` part from routes!!!

**Script**

```
<script>
  function onUpload(event) {
  var name = event.fpfile.filename;
  jQuery.ajax({
   data: { "attachment[name]": name },
   type: 'post',
   url: "/attachments"
  });
 }
</script>
```

Comment: I mentioned this above but to clarify, now when I upload the file, name has a value and title is nil. But when I hit the submit button title has a value and name is nil. I am trying to find a way now to avoid this. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: @user3318660 remove `f.submit` part from yr form, because u already submitting it through ajax with `onchange: 'onUpload(event)'`. Also make sure yr `var name = event.fpfile.filename;` stores name. 1st yr ajax requests, then yr submit button requests it.

Comment: Yeah I went ahead and removed f.submit and added this to my JavaScript. Works fine now. Thanks everyone for their help! `success: function(data) { $('#simple_form_id').submit();`

Answer (score 0):

```
@attachment = current_user.attachments.build(attachment_params)
@attachment.user_id = current_user.id
```

You don't need to assgn `current_user.id`, because in first line you have build attachment with current_user

```
@foo = params[:name]
@attachment.name = @foo
```

That code is redundant, I think. Why you assign `params[:name]` to `@foo` ? If you have `:name` attribute in permit of `attactment_params` you don't need them.

Just

```
@attachment = current_user.attachments.build(attachment_params)
if @attacment.save
..
..
```

If you don't have it, you can use `merge` of params like this

```
@attachment = current_user.attachments.build(attachment_params.merge(name: params[:name]))
@attachment.save
..
..
```

Oh also you can merge in params method, rather than merge in action.

```
def attachment_params
 params.require(:attachment).permit(:user_id).merge(name: params[:name])
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried both implementations but I am getting this in my terminal. `Processing by AttachmentsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"name"=>"myFile.docx"}
  User Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 53ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: attachment):
  app/controllers/attachments_controller.rb:44:in 'attachment_params'
  app/controllers/attachments_controller.rb:12:in 'create'`

Comment: The name is still not getting saved. Other suggestions I have read is to have another controller handle this? I don't get the attachment params error when I comment out the JS in my view. So possibly I did not write my JS properly.

Comment: Have you try to change with this `data : { 'attactment[name]' : name }` ? also on route you don't need `/:name`